# Age range to numerical values to calcutate Correlation of CD consumption with age range

Tags: python, sorting, machine-learning, heatmap, correlation

I did sort the values. But the problem is 'до 25' (up to 25). How can i change it into '0-25' and calculate correlation coefficient of age group and overall rating.

Some of my data is below

| Age group | Overall rating |
| --- | --- |
| 65 and older | 38.45 |
| 55-64 | 17.66 |
| up to 25 | 46.56 |
| 45-54 | 24.95 |
| 35-44 | 33.54 |
| 25-34 | 37.21 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how you can do what you ask.  I converted your age categories to mean age because correlation requires two numeric values; a category will not work for correlation.  There are some other problems with your data.  It is unclear what the 65 and older class really is numerically.  I made it 65-100 but that may not be the case.  You also have your categories set at 25-34 for example.  It should be 25-35 because 25-35 does not contain 35 it contains 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33 and 34 which is what I think you are trying to achieve.  I did not change this but you should change it if that is what you are trying to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Agelst=['65 and older','55-64','up to 25','45-54','35-44','25-34']
Ratelst=[38.45,17.66,46.56,24.95,33.54,37.21]

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Age_Group']=Agelst
df['Overal_Rating']=Ratelst

display(df)

#Change 'up to 25' to '0-25'
df.replace('up to 25', '0-25',inplace=True)
df.replace('65 and older', '65-100',inplace=True)

display(df)

#You will need a numeric age to use for correlation.  We can develop one from the strings in your 'Age_Group'
loweragelst=[]
upperagelst=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    loweragelst.append(int(((df.iloc[i]['Age_Group']).split('-'))[0]))
    upperagelst.append(int(((df.iloc[i]['Age_Group']).split('-'))[1]))

df['Lower_Age']=loweragelst
df['Upper_Age']=upperagelst

#Sort the df
df.sort_values(by=['Lower_Age'], ascending=True,inplace=True)
display(df)

#Add a mean age column to use for correlation
df['Mean_Age']=(df['Lower_Age']+df['Upper_Age'])/2

display(df)

#Calculate Pearson's Correlation
X=df['Mean_Age']
Y=df['Overal_Rating']
PCor= pearsonr(X, Y)
print(PCor)
```

The resulting df and correlation are:

```
Age_Group   Overal_Rating
0   65 and older    38.45
1   55-64   17.66
2   up to 25    46.56
3   45-54   24.95
4   35-44   33.54
5   25-34   37.21
    Age_Group   Overal_Rating
0   65-100  38.45
1   55-64   17.66
2   0-25    46.56
3   45-54   24.95
4   35-44   33.54
5   25-34   37.21
    Age_Group   Overal_Rating   Lower_Age   Upper_Age
2   0-25    46.56   0   25
5   25-34   37.21   25  34
4   35-44   33.54   35  44
3   45-54   24.95   45  54
1   55-64   17.66   55  64
0   65-100  38.45   65  100
    Age_Group   Overal_Rating   Lower_Age   Upper_Age   Mean_Age
2   0-25    46.56   0   25  12.5
5   25-34   37.21   25  34  29.5
4   35-44   33.54   35  44  39.5
3   45-54   24.95   45  54  49.5
1   55-64   17.66   55  64  59.5
0   65-100  38.45   65  100     82.5

PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.4489402583278369, pvalue=0.37183097344063043)
```

Comment: Awesome @lelelel ! Would you please accept the answer so that I get credit for it?  Thank you.